# scrollView images are not in the center using midX?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I used two statements in my code when initializing newX variable which I believe they should give the same result but one didn't, which are:

```
( scrollView.frame.size.width / 2 ) - 75
```

And

```
scrollView.frame.midX - 75
```

here is my code, look for the comment at the middle:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
var images = [UIImageView]()

var contentWidth: CGFloat = 0.0
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
    for i in 0...2 {
        
        let image = UIImage(named: "icon\(i).png")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        
        //  Here is the problem
        let newX = (scrollView.frame.size.width / 2 + scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i)) - 75
        let newY = scrollView.frame.midY - 75
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: newX, y: newY, width: 150, height: 150)
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        contentWidth += scrollView.frame.size.width
        
    }
    
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: view.frame.size.height)
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = false
    scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
}}
```

The first one perfectly centred the images, but when I replaced it with the second on it didn't center them as shown in the picture here
[Code Representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naFKI.png) . why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that midX is considering also the position of the scrollview's origin, so midX would be half the width of your scrollView + the X origin of your scrollView. (Similar to how minX is not always 0)

Width, on the other hand, is, well, the width of the scrollView, which is absolute.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I couldn't quite understand, what do you mean by the origin?

Comment: Origin meaning the location of the top left corner of your view.

Comment: Oh, so if the origin is at 0, midX will work and that explains why midY worked fine! I really appreciate it Tonton, Thank you!